# How to add extension to ruby Tempfile object?

Tags: ruby, file, temporary-files

How to add extension for `Tempfile` object?

```
image_path = "https://api.tinify.com/output/g85retpckb5fz2x8zpjrvtj0jcv1txm0"
image = open(image_path)
image.path # "/tmp/open-uri20191225-21585-oo95rb"
```

Now I want to make this file has *jpg* extension how can I do that?

I have also tried to convert it to `File` class but couldn't change extension too.

```
new_image = File.new(image)
new_image.path # "/tmp/open-uri20191225-21585-oo95rb"
```

Comment: Why do you want to have a _temporary_ file to have a specific extension? Why do you care?

Comment: I will save it as paperclip file.

Comment: @spickermann In my case I was just dumping some Swift code auto-generated by Ruby into a temporary file then launching it into my editor for manual vetting, before copying it into parts of an XCode project. It was just a quick way to get some repetitive work done. A correct filename extension meant that the text editor auto-detected the filetype and activated appropriate syntax highlighting and other extensions, which obviously was helpful and just saved an extra step of selecting that manually. So - an unusual case perhaps - but there are times when this kind of thing is useful `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FileUtils#mv` to physically move the file over the filesystem.

```rb
image_path = "https://api.tinify.com/output/g85retpckb5fz2x8zpjrvtj0jcv1txm0"
image = open(image_path)
image.path # "/tmp/open-uri20191225-21585-oo95rb"

image_path_jpg = "#{image.path}.jpg"
FileUtils.mv(image.path, image_path_jpg)
image = open(image_path_jpg)
image.path # "/tmp/open-uri20191225-21585-oo95rb.jpg"
```

Please note that you are responsible for file deletion now, since the file is not a temp file anymore.

Comment: Perhaps add a note that the OP has now to delete the file by themself because it is not a temp file anymore?

Answer (score 12):

If you're creating the Tempfile yourself [you can do](https://makandracards.com/makandra/13719-ruby-how-to-ensure-a-tempfile-s-extension)

```
>> Tempfile.new([ 'foobar', '.xlsx' ]).path
=> "/tmp/foobar20130115-19153-1xhbncb-0.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Modifying the tempfile module**

To add extension to a Ruby tempfile, I figured that `tempfile` module needs to be modified a little.

Make a class like this:

```
require 'tempfile'

class CustomTempfle < Tempfile
  def initialize(filename, temp_dir = nil)
    temp_dir ||= Dir.tmpdir
    extension = File.extname(filename)
    basename = File.basename(filename, extension)
    super([basename, extension], temp_dir)
  end
end
```

And then you can call the class and provide the `filename` with the extensio and write to the file like so.

```
CustomTempfle.open('filename.pdf', nil) do |tmp|
  File.open(tmp, 'wb') { |f| f << 'content_of_the_file' }
end
```